# Using filter in plotOutput for dynamic User defined data in Shiny app

Tags: r, graphics, shiny

I'm finding trouble in filtering data for ggplot2 visualization. I want to use a filter and put in f value, like using

```
data %>%
filter(Col == Number) 
ggplot()
```

to have customizable plot according to datasets

I used this code to generate a Shiny app that will able the user to upload data and can interactively plot it, but the filter is not working.
:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    h1(' output'),
    h2('Graphics'),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput(inputId = 'file1', label = 'Upload your Data:', accept=c('text/csv', 
                                                                           'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                                                           '.csv')),
        tags$hr(), 

        selectInput('xcol', "X variable:", "", selected = ""),
        selectInput('ycol', 'Y variable:', "", selected = ""), 
        selectInput('filter1', 'Filter:', "", selected = "", multiple = TRUE),
        selectInput('filter2', 'Filter Value',"",selected = "")
      ),

      mainPanel(

        plotOutput("plot")

      )
    )

  )

)

server <- shinyServer(function(session, input, output){


   data <- reactive({

       req(input$file1)
       inFile <- input$file1 
       df <- read_csv(inFile$datapath)#, header = T, sep=",")



       updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X variable:',
                         choices = names(df), selected = names(df))
       updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y variable:',
                        choices = names(df), selected = names(df))
       updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'filter1', label = 'Filter:',
                         choices = names(df), selected ="")
       observe({
       updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'filter2', label = 'Filter value', choices =c(0:10))
       })  
       return(df)

   }) 

   output$plot <- renderPlot({
     F1 <- input$filter1
     F2 <- input$filter2

       data() %>% filter(F1==F2)%>% 
       ggplot(aes(x =data()[input$xcol],y= data()[input$ycol]))+ 
       geom_point()

})
        })




shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't do any subsetting in the `ggplot()` call. You also don't need to (and in fact, shouldn't) specify `data()` in the `ggplot()` call. This is how I might do it (although it's hard to test if you don't provide reproducible data):

```
x_var <- reactive(input$xcol)
y_var <- reactive(input$ycol)

data() %>%
    filter(F1 == F2) %>%
    ggplot(aes_string(x = x_var(), y = y_var())) +
    geom_point()
```

More on my last point, consider the difference between the following:

```
mtcars %>% filter(carb == 2) %>% ggplot(aes(x = carb, y = wt)) + geom_point()
# this works!
```

```
mtcars %>% filter(carb == 2) %>% ggplot(aes(x = mtcars$carb, y = mtcars$wt)) + geom_point()
# this doesn't
```

The latter doesn't work because it's trying to plot `mtcars$carb`, instead of the filtered (`mtcars == 2`) vector.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in this case, it only will take on  data point not the whole column to do the plotting. if we used, x_var as time series, and y_var as continuous variable; it will show one point at a time not all data.

Comment: Hi @Mutaz, see my edit--does that work? I think we need `aes_string` when passing in variables programatically.

Comment: thank you, but nothing changes, in fact, it will give a clear graph when trying to plot, even when trying different datasets

Comment: Okay. In the future, try to provide some data so that people trying to help are able to use the same data as you.

Comment: Thank you so much, @heds1! but I'm trying to use it as data visualizer, not for a particular dataset.

Comment: No problem. Yes the purpose of the data doesn't matter, but it's helpful to provide reproducible data so that other people are working on the same page as you are, otherwise (like in this case) it's hard to come up with a solution. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info :)